# How to have a conditional function based on another argument

Tags: typescript

I want to have a function that takes another function and the signature of that function changes depending on another argument passed to that function.

For example:

```js
function doSomething<AllowNull extends boolean>({ allowNull, onChange }: { allowNull: AllowNull, onChange: AllowNull extends true ? (input: number | null) => void : (input: number) => void }) {
  if (allowNull) {
    onChange(null);
  } else {
    onChange(1);
  }
}
```

However Typescript complains that `null` can't be passed to `onChange` because it does not narrow the signature.

I tried this with function overloading too:

```js
function doSomething(props: { allowNull: true, onChange: (input: number | null) => void }): void
function doSomething(props: { allowNull: false, onChange: (input: number) => void }): void
function doSomething({ allowNull, onChange }: { allowNull: boolean,onChange: (input: number | null) => void }): void {
  if (allowNull) {
    onChange(null);
  } else {
    onChange(1);
  }
}
```

But Typescript complains that one of the overloads signature is not compatible with the implementation.

How does one achieve this pattern in a type safe way?

[Link to TS playground so you can see the errors.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIBMHsFMGcB2ByALuA7tATga0wJaoAW4AxtIpEQZQIYA2wAZgK6Jmq2JTQDK0ALawSBRAHMAPAEEGDaBgByrOeFgAPVLCrxwAI2jQGsOogB8ACgDe4RvKUqGAGnCUAwsVPjY4AL4AucBs7BWU5QNl7MOdXRA8vWAi5UMc1TW1IXVRsVh8AfnALMQAHVlRAxFZBPVhscAAfcEq5AEpwAF4zcAA3aAJIcECixFLypqqa7DbOnr6B3zarYHBwAmZCkIdWoOWV2PiJWAtmhhaAbl3fNQZ4HyW9-c9DiwBGc8vgX2BvsF4EFHQWDwhBI4DYHC4lFc3Vq8jo1AkLHYnG4vAEwlEEgAojcjsVsNBivBAsFklsGIFsrkXO4nt4hiUyhUJrUGuNtjNev0-C1AlzIEiIaiYOiRMQxOIcbcLPjCcSgrYydFAsxGLcaXE6YlCoyxpVqrVpl1%20Ty%20XNBSioSKhGKJVKjqSoo4NQdvH4SYqneF9IZjKYnLSEgyRkzxga6o0TkbZtyFmbufdVusLJtootditA88oxcVldYLidg8s95Xu8858gA)

Comment: That seems hellishly complicated. Why do you need this?

Comment: It seems like what you actually want is to make input optional `input?: number`

Comment: @Liam it's not that complicated. If `allowNull` is passed to the function then the second function can take `null`. I do not want this to always be optional.

This is for a React input component that in some circumstances is allowed to have no value set and in others must always.

Comment: so what's wrong with two functions? That seems infinitely simpler.

Comment: @Liam because there is a huge amount of other logic associated with this input component (validation, parsing of expressions, arrow key and shift key logic for incrementing decrementing) that I do not want to repeat just to make it sometimes nullable and it is non-trivial to do so. The implementation of having a property `allowNull` is by far the simplest implementation its only expressing it through Typescript that is difficult, `allowNull` affects multiple aspects of this input in reality but this is the part TS can't handle

I have just offered a greatly simplified view onto the problem.

Comment: Neither overloads nor generics are going to be very helpful here for what you're trying to do; I'd suggest using a *discriminated union* parameter type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbAO9N).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that works. I had tried this but I was on a version prior to 4.6 when I did and the destructuring issue that the accepted answer mentioned caught me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a union in the the arguments. This will allow Typescript (4.6 and newer) to narrow `onChange` based on `allowNull`:

```
function doSomething({ allowNull, onChange }:
    | { allowNull: true, onChange: (input: number | null) => void }
    | { allowNull: false, onChange: (input: number) => void }): void {
    if (allowNull) {
        onChange(null);
    } else {
        onChange(1);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYIMoILYFMYAWcEA5gBQDeyAhgDa0IDuAcmPQDTJIDCB1puZAF8AXMGQTkAH2RU6DFm1ojkMAE5hcnHnwEqyxAA5gYKiGGwAjXGunJz9AJTIAvAD5kANwRxUw8ZIycvRMrPQqIHQAzlpcELz8JLj6RiZmFtZqzu5ePn5CjirevrIBEnAgyGTyoUrOFGWSEjqJuGQOtI4A3I1CyLi0MaVNTS0CZACM3b3AQsDAQA)

For pre 4.6 you can't destructure in the parameters, but you can still narrow: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYIMoILYFMYAWcEA5gBQAOAXMMncgD7IDeyAhgDYcIDuAcmC5VkMAE5hcAGmRIAwgTalcwssQpgYwiGGwAjXKMbJtXAJTIAvAD5kANwRxUyAL616TVp279BHYSE4AZykZCHlFEmVkVQh1TWMdfVFzazsHJ2dTYXtHFjc6OBBoigA6L14BMzz6GuRSuQUlMhMOUwBufJdkXA5g6tq6erDGyLIARnbO11dgIA)

Comment: Relevant documentation link for [narrowing for destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions). You might also want to mention [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) in general here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had actually tried this before upgrading to 4.6 and forgot to re-attempt it after!

Comment: Also looks like even in TypeScript 4.6 destructuring with a default parameter breaks it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgEQPYGVsC2EwAFgJYB2A5lALxQDeAUFK8ktgO7xID8AXFABm7AM4QA3C1bYKAYRLJqEQQApKYOMEEU4BVBABOASjoA+KADdsZACZSAvlKahIUHPiKlKNes1ZQ7AhcPAiCwIZwktJQsgpKVCpQ6hSa2lC6+kZQAD4ZiAimtBbWdo7OQnAUAMbAZLJQtniExOTUqgyBHNwFdMJiEAA0sfKKylAO-DG5sAVoGB4t3tTTeYtebVTGgqW2jNNkQslBIQWm-gGXcWOJqrpIxlKXDlAQCOL7l1ejCRCqAIyPaYOJggphAA